# Conversion NSString to const char string[]

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsstring, character

I have one query related conversion
I have one NSString object with content some string like below

```
NSString *string = @"do nothing";
```

Now I am trying to pass string in below code like

```
const char inputString[] =  string;
```

Xcode showing error

> Array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal.

Is there any workaround for the same.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simpliest is to use UTF-8 conversion (which replaces the old and long deprecated `- (const char *)cString` method):

```
const char *Cstr = myObjCStr.UTF8String;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSString *string = @"do nothing";
const char * inputString = [string UTF8String];
```

If you want to use other encoding,use this `cStringUsingEncoding`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not satisfy with C array like `const char * inputString`

Then you may try below code -

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *str = @"do nothing";
for (int i = 0; i < [str length]; i++) {
    NSString *ch = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
    [array addObject:ch];
}
```